# Exercise of statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Hello  I can not understand how to get the formula for the result in this stash exercise:

**EXERCISE:**
*A computer store owner estimates that 45 percent of customers entering his store buy a computer, 15 percent buy a smartphone, while the remaining 40 percent only enter for curiosity and leave without purchasing. If there are 5 customers in your store on a given day, what is the probability that you sell exactly 2 computers and 1 smartphone? Suggestion. Calculate the probability of selling three objects when 5 customers enter.*

**SOLUTION:**

The probability of buying 3 objects is:

[Image Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8puR.png)

How does the formula get result?

Comment: The link gives you the probability of $3$ objects when $5$ customers enter. For this have a look at [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Actually it does not solve the original problem, and I don't really like the suggestion. You better have a look at [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).